# editing the UItableview using barbutton item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i am trying to edit the UItableview .
what i am doing is trying to diplay a leftbarButton on my navigation bar

i wrote this code in my viewdidload

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.editButtonItem];
```

but its not showing any button on my navigation bar :S

P.S : My currentview is subview of tabbarcontroller and i am using UItableView and UInavigationbar in my interfacebuilder .

can any one help me

thanks in advance

regards

Edit : I am not using UItableViewController

i cant get this work if i dont use UItableViewController .

Comment: I think the self.editButtonItem is owned by UITableViewController instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITabBarController and UINavigationController work as container, they can contain other UIViewController's instances inside. So, you can use UITabBarController to contain sub view which are UITableViewController's subclasses.

You can read the sample codes of [TheElements](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007419) and [LocateMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801). They use UITabBarController to manage other UIViewController instances. Like [TheElements](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007419), it manages UITableViewController instances by UITabBarController.

And then, you can display the edit button of UITableViewController.

Or, you can use the method of [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943) to enter the editing mode or leave the editing mode.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where have you placed the above code in? It should be in the viewDidLoad of the tableView implementation file

Ideally, init the navigation controller with your tableview controller. Then place the above code you've written inside the viewDidLoad of the tableViewController. It should work normally as expected.

Comment: i am not using tableViewController ,now what i have to do ?

Comment: Then more information in detail would be helpful. Like how your view hierarchy looks like. Is it like one of the tabs in the tab bar has a view which is navigation based? If so, place your button code in that particular viewDidLoad of the viewcontroller which you load for that tab

Comment: well exactly , i place that code in  viewdidload of that view but i am not getting . I searched around , i found that i have to implement some other method if i dont use UItableviewController but i dont know what to implement and where to :S